# Pyserial read is not returning what I write out

Tags: python, encoding, raspberry-pi, pyserial

currently I have a raspberry pi ports connected to two serial devices. the devices are usb to RS485/RS422 converter. both are connected with wires to the proper terminals (terminal 1 of device A to terminal 2 of device B, terminal 2 of device A to terminal 1 of device B).

I'm able to successfully read and write from one device to the other, however the return read data is not the same as the data I wrote.

For example, if the message I am trying to send is "Te", the message I read is `b'U\x13\x00'`.

I am currently running python 3 on buster.

```py
ser = serial.Serial(port='port 1', baudrate = 9600)
message = "Te"
message = message.encode('ascii')
while True:
     ser.write(message)
     time.sleep(1)
```

write.py

```py
ser = serial.Serial(port = 'port 2', baudrate = 9600)
while True:
     serial_line = ser.read(50)#placehoder until I am able to get correct values
     print(serial_line)
```

read.py

I except the output of bytes in read to convert to the string I wrote in write.py, however the output is always something completely different.

EDIT:
[link to serial devices](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005CPI0JQ)(usb to RS-485/RS-422)

Comment: Why are you encoding the message before sending it?

Comment: If I write without encoding, it throws a type error stating Unicode strings aren't supported and to encode it into bytes

Comment: What exactly are these devices?  Talking about "terminal 1" and "terminal 2" is meaningless without more information.  And what are you actually writing to them?  The code you posted writes `test`, which is not defined anywhere.

Comment: thank you for catching that, that was a typo cleaning up my code and putting it on here. The correct variable was supposed to be message. As for the devices, they are two germo mini usb to RS485/RS422 converter ftdi chip's connected to the same raspberry pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wiring seems to be wrong:

> ... terminal 1 of device A to terminal 2 of device B, terminal 2 of device A to terminal 1 of device B...

That's OK for UART or RS232, but for RS485 the correct wiring is A to A and B to B (straight instead of crossing RX to TX).

Rewire and it'll work.

Comment: Thank you so much this was it! I was strictly told to wire up as I stated for it to work so this is probably the last thing I would've checked. youre a life saver!

Comment: Writing a detailed question gave you the price. I'm glad you fixed it.